# Разные перегрузки универсального метода в зависимости от указанного типа

Tags: c#, generics, методы

товарищи! Наткнулся я тут на старенькое [интеревью с Джоном Скитом на хабре](https://habr.com/post/201316/). В его рамках Джон задал читателям следующий вопрос:

> Как вы можете заставить этот код скомпилироваться, так чтобы он вызвал
>   три различные перегрузки метода?

```
void Foo()
{
    EvilMethod<string>();
    EvilMethod<int>();
    EvilMethod<int?>();
}
```

Мне не совсем понятно, как можно реализовать такую вещь, ведь даже если использовать *where*, то мы получаем ошибку, что метод с таким же названием и параметрами уже существует. На SO искал, в Google тоже (возможно, искал плохо, так что если что - палками не бейте)) Будет очень интересно выслушать ваши идеи, так что заранее спасибо)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Удалось сделать только так:

```
public interface IEvilMethod<T1>
{   
    void EvilMethod<T2>();
}

public class Example : IEvilMethod<int>, IEvilMethod<int?>, IEvilMethod<string>
{
    public void Foo()
    {
        ((IEvilMethod<int>) this).EvilMethod<int>();
        ((IEvilMethod<int?>) this).EvilMethod<int?>();
        ((IEvilMethod<string>) this).EvilMethod<string>();
    }

    void IEvilMethod<int>.EvilMethod<T>()   
    {
        Console.WriteLine(typeof(T));
    }

    void IEvilMethod<int?>.EvilMethod<T>()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(typeof(T));
    }

    void IEvilMethod<string>.EvilMethod<T>()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(typeof(T));
    }
}
```

---

**Update**

Нашел решение [здесь](http://aakinshin.net/ru/blog/post/jon-skeet-quiz/).

```
public class ReferenceGeneric<T> where T : class { }

public class EvilClassBase
{
  protected void EvilMethod<T>()
  {
    Console.WriteLine("int?");
  }
}

public class EvilClass : EvilClassBase
{
  public void Run()
  {
    EvilMethod<string>();
    EvilMethod<int>();
    EvilMethod<int?>();
  }

  private void EvilMethod<T>(ReferenceGeneric<T> arg = null) where T : class
  {
    Console.WriteLine("string");
  }

  private void EvilMethod<T>(T? arg = null) where T : struct
  {
    Console.WriteLine("int");
  }
}
```

Comment: И правда очень интересное решение) Спасибо Вам, багаж знаний пополнен)